# How can I transpose x and y axis on a Plot?

Tags: plotting, graphics

This question has appeared in various forms online, but I have not yet seen a complete answer, so I am posting it here.

More specifically, suppose I have a function

```
F: X->Y
```

that is not one-to-one. *Mathematica* can easily plot this function as follows:

```
Plot[F[x], {x, 0, 30}, PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {0, 1}}]
```

This produces a graph that passes the vertical line test, but does not pass the horizontal line test, because F is not one-to-one. My question is, how do I get a plot of the inverse relation (which is not a function) for all Y?

Edit: I am adding the function F for clarity. I originally omitted it because I figured a generic solution would solve it.

```
F[x_] := (1000 * x) / 24279 * Sqrt[-1 + x^(2/7)]
```

Edit 2: I am adding the graph (that I am trying to graph the inverse relation of) I produced using Plot for further clarity.

[image]

To be clear, this image is produced by the following three commands:

```
F[x_] := (1000 * x) / (24279 * Sqrt[-1 + x^(2/7)])
myplot = Plot[F[x], {x,0,30}, PlotRange -> {{0,30}, {0,1}}]
Export["foo.png", myplot]
```

Comment: Have you used [ParametricPlot](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ParametricPlot.html) yet?

Comment: That is a nice suggestion. I guess I could use X = T, Y = F[T], and that should do it. I didn't think of doing that before although I was aware of ParametricPlot.

Comment: @whuber, this does not quite work because F is not defined over all the real numbers, and I cannot compute the exact boundary of the domain of F.

Comment: That is, for certain values of T in my plot window, I get errors like "Infinite Expression 1/Sqrt[0.] encountered."

Comment: Please update your question with the code that defines F.

Comment: @m_goldberg,As requested, I've added a definition for F.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7859/5 and http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7191/5

Comment: Previous question on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6204898/618728

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Update:**

Using  the example function provided in op's update:

```
ff[x_] := (1000*x)/(24279*Sqrt[-1 + x^(2/7)]);

prmtrcplt1 = ParametricPlot[{x, ff[x]}, {x, 0, 30},
  PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {0, 1}}, ImageSize -> 300, AspectRatio -> 1];

prmtrcplt2 = ParametricPlot[{ff[x], x}, {x, 0, 30},
  PlotRange -> Reverse[PlotRange[prmtrcplt1]], ImageSize -> 300,  AspectRatio -> 1];

Row[{prmtrcplt1, prmtrcplt2}, Spacer[5]]
```

[image]

```
plt = Plot[ff[x], {x, 0, 30}, PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {0, 1}},ImageSize -> 300,
   AspectRatio -> 1];

ref1 = MapAt[GeometricTransformation[#, ReflectionTransform[{-1, 1}]] &, plt, {1}];

ref2 = plt /. line_Line :> GeometricTransformation[line, ReflectionTransform[{-1, 1}]];

Row[{plt, Graphics[ref1[[1]], PlotRange -> Reverse@PlotRange[ref1], ref1[[2]]],
  Graphics[ref2[[1]], PlotRange -> Reverse@PlotRange[ref2], ref2[[2]]]}, Spacer[5]]
```

[image]

---

original post

**ParametricPlot** (as suggested by whuber)

```
prmtrcplt1 = ParametricPlot[{x, x Sin[2 x]}, {x, -Pi, Pi},
   PlotRange -> {{-Pi, Pi}, {-3, 3}}, ImageSize -> 300];

prmtrcplt2 = ParametricPlot[{x Sin[2 x], x}, {x, -Pi, Pi},
  PlotRange -> {{-Pi, Pi}, {-3, 3}}, ImageSize -> 300];

Row[{prmtrcplt1, prmtrcplt2}, Spacer[5]]
```

[image]

**Post-process using ReflectionTransform**

```
reflected = plt /. line_Line :> {Red,  
     GeometricTransformation[line, ReflectionTransform[{-1, 1}]]};

Row[{plt, reflected, 
     Show[plt, Plot[x, {x, -Pi, Pi}, PlotStyle -> Black], reflected,
      PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 300]}, Spacer[5]]
```

[image]

Variations:

```
reflected2 = MapAt[GeometricTransformation[#, ReflectionMatrix[{-1, 1}]] &, plt, {1}];

reflected3 = MapAt[GeometricTransformation[#, ReflectionTransform[{-1, 1}]] &,plt, {1}]
```

Comment: ParametricPlot gives the error I mentioned above, RotationTransform as used above gives an empty graph, and I am trying ReflectionTransform.

Comment: @merlin2011, just saw your update with the specific form of `F`; will check what is needed to change to handle that case. Btw, what is the value of `z` in your definition of `F` (or was it meant to be `x`)?

Comment: meant to be x, will fix.

Comment: Can you apply the function *Reverse* in *RelievePlot*? I did unsuccessfully with `Reverse[ReliefPlot[Cdata, PlotLegends -> Automatic, FrameTicks -> True, DataRange -> Automatic]]`.

Answer (score 20):

From an [earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6209255/618728) of mine:

```
axisFlip = # /. {
     x_Line | x_GraphicsComplex :> MapAt[# ~Reverse~ 2 &, x, 1],
     x : (PlotRange -> _) :> x ~Reverse~ 2
   } &;
```

Example of use:

```
F[x_] := (1000*x)/(24279*Sqrt[-1 + x^(2/7)])
myplot = Plot[F[x], {x, 0, 30}, PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {0, 1}}]

myplot // axisFlip
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

One of the nice things about this method is the ability to easily use `Filling`:

```
Plot[{Sin[x], .5 Sin[2 x]}, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}] // axisFlip
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Your answer is wonderful! But the figure after `axisFlip` cannot `Show` with other figures.

Comment: @EdenHarder It works fine here.  Please try this example: `g1 = Plot[{Sin[x], .5 Sin[2 x]}, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}] // axisFlip; g2 = Plot[1 + 5 Sinc[10 x], {x, -1, 1}]; Show[g1, g2]`.

Comment: Please try this example: `g1 = Plot[{Sin[x], .5 Sin[2 x]}, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
   Filling -> {1 -> {2}}] // axisFlip; g2 = 
 Plot[1 + 5 Sinc[10 x], {x, -2, 2}, Filling -> Bottom]; Show[g1, g2, 
 PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {0, 7}}]`

Comment: @Eden That works too, unless you are referring to the clipping in `g2` which may be corrected by adding `PlotRange -> All`.  Result:  http://i.stack.imgur.com/9znY4.png  Are you seeing something else?

Comment: Yeah, it works! But why `PlotRange -> All` is needed?

Comment: @Eden Regions outside the `PlotRange` are simply not rendered by `Plot`, therefore if it doesn't appear in `g2` it cannot appear in `Show[g1, g2]` either.  You cannot increase a `PlotRange` after-the-fact.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

This is an ill formed sketch of an idea, but by allowing the output value of your function to be a set you can still maintain a 1 to 1 mapping.

Define a multi valued function:

```
g[x_] := {2 x} /; x < 10
g[x_] := {2 x, x} /; 10 <= x <= 20
g[x_] := {2 x, x, Sin@x} /; x > 20
```

A function to list plot a multi-valued function:

```
Clear@multiValueListPlot
multiValueListPlot[f_, {start_, stop_, step_: 100}] := 
 Function[{x, ys}, 
    Point[{x, #}] & /@ ys] @@@ ({#, f@#} & /@ 
     Range[start, stop, (stop - start)/step]) // Graphics

Show[multiValueListPlot[g, {1, 40, 300}], Frame -> True]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

For square roots:

```
Show[multiValueListPlot[y /. Solve[y^2 == #] &, {0, 40, 300}], 
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"X", "Square Roots"}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]