# ListPlot and filling between curves

Tags: plotting, filling

I have a simple question. Why is `Filling` not working in the following?

```
ListLinePlot[{{{0,0},{1,1}},{{5,0},{6,1}}}, Filling->{1->{2}}]
```

I am simply plotting two lines defined by two pairs of points, and I want to fill between them. Why is this not working as expected? It seems really easy.

Comment: I use my `axisFlip` function for this as illustrated here: [(18669)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18669/121)

Answer (score 5):

You can simply add a background polygon:

```
ListLinePlot[{{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}, {{5, 0}, {6, 1}}}, 
 Prolog -> {LightBlue, Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {6, 1}, {5, 0}}]}]
```

> [image: plot]

Or you can flip the axes twice using the following modification of Mr.Wizard's [`axisFlip` function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18669/280):

```
axisFlip[l_List] := 
  Replace[l, {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ} :> {y, x}, {-2}];
axisFlip[g_Graphics] := g /. {
    x : (_Point | _Line | _GraphicsComplex) :> MapAt[axisFlip, x, 1],
    x : (PlotRange -> _) :> x~Reverse~2};

ListLinePlot[axisFlip@{{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}, {{5, 0}, {6, 1}}}, 
  Filling -> {1 -> {2}}] // axisFlip

ListPlot[{Table[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi, 0.1}], 
    Table[Sinc[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi, 0.1}]}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, 
  FillingStyle -> {Red, Blue}, Frame -> True] // axisFlip

Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Filling -> Axis] // axisFlip
```

> [image: plot]
>   [image: plot]
>   [image: plot]

Comment: *"but this method is dangerous and can have unexpected side-effects in some cases"* -- such as?  Is it because your replacement is a bit too general?  I do not see any problems if I use [my own `axisFlip` function](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18669/121) for the outer operation.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thank you. For the purposes of this answer I have extended your function for `ListPlot` and for `List`s.

Answer (score 5):

Modifying the `MapAt+GeometricTransformation` approach in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18656/125) in the related Q/A linked by @Mr.Wizard:

```
ClearAll[filledLLP]
filledLLP[l_, o : OptionsPattern[{Graphics, ListLinePlot}]] := 
 Graphics[MapAt[GeometricTransformation[#, ReflectionMatrix[{-1, 1}]] &, 
    ListLinePlot[Reverse[l, 3], FilterRules[{o}, Options[ListLinePlot]]], {1}][[1]],
  FilterRules[{o}, Options[Graphics]], 
  AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, Axes -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

Examples:

```
lists = {{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}, {{5, 0}, {6, 1}}};
llp0 = ListLinePlot[lists, ImageSize -> 400, BaseStyle -> Thick];
llpX = filledLLP[lists, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, FillingStyle -> Yellow,
    ImageSize -> 400, BaseStyle -> Thick];

Row[{llp0, llpX}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

```
filledLLP[{{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}, {{1, .2}, {4, .5}}, {{5, 0}, {6, 1}}}, 
 Filling -> {2 -> {{3}, Opacity[1, Red]}, 
   2 -> {{1}, Opacity[1, Yellow]}, 1 -> {{3}, Opacity[.25, Cyan]}}, 
 ImageSize -> 400, BaseStyle -> Thick]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

Using version 10.

The filling is the intersection of the half-plane to the right of the left line with the half-plane to the left of the right line.

```
RegionPlot[
 RegionIntersection[
  HalfPlane[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}, {1, 0}],
  HalfPlane[{{5, 0}, {6, 1}}, {-1, 0}]],
 PlotRange -> {{0, 6}, {0, 1}}]
```

[image]