# How to transpose x and y axis on a LogLogPlot?

Tags: plotting

how can i exchange x and y Axis of this loglogplot?

```
x1[y_] := y+3
x2[y_] := y-1

myplot = LogLogPlot[{x1[y], x2[y]}, {y, 10^-4, 100}, PlotRange -> Full, 
  PlotPoints -> 10, PlotLegends -> "Expressions", ImageSize -> 600, 
  AspectRatio -> Full, Filling -> None]
```

this is a simple example, my real functions of X are very complicated and i can not find Y with explicit function of x.

1. Is there any way to switch the axis of this `LogLogPlot`?
2. How can I export this plot data point in a matrix?

Comment: Why is the `LogLog` part relevant?

Comment: Its relevant because there is no `ParametricLogLogPlot..`

Comment: related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18669/2079.  Note `axisFlip` does not work correctly however, but may be a start

Answer (score 4):

This works for your example:

```
 y1 = InverseFunction[FunctionInterpolation[x1[y], {y, 10^-4, 100}]]
 y2 = InverseFunction[FunctionInterpolation[x2[y], {y, 10^-4, 100}]]
 LogLogPlot[{y1[x],y2[x]}, {x, 10^-3, 100}]
```

However I'm afraid `FunctionInterpolation` might not do a good job of sampling depending on your function.

You can do this:

```
 y1 = InverseFunction[x1]
 y2 = InverseFunction[x2]
 LogLogPlot[{y2[x], y1[x]}, {x, 10^-3, 100}]
```

But it might be painfully slow as it effectively iterates to find every plot point.

Here is a bit of a hack to fix the axes after using `axisFlip`: (`LogLogPlot` does something weird with `PlotRange` so you can't simply transpose the range as `axisFlip` does )

(https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18669/2079)

```
Show[LogLogPlot[ Null, {x, 3, 100},
   PlotRange -> {{10^-3, 100}, {10^-4, 100}}], myplot // axisFlip]
```

[image]

Comment: i couldn't use of axisFlip, the error is: "Could not combine the graphics objects in Show"

Comment: you need to copy and evaluate the definition of `axisFlip` from the linked answer.

Comment: Wow, It works! you are lifesaving!

Comment: @george209  Very nice! Could you elaborate on the "hack" required for LogLogPlot. It looks like maybe you are plotting nothing (Null) but setting the Axis needed for the flipped plot.  Would you have to do something like this for LogPlot and LogLinearPlot as well?

Answer (score 4):

Use `ListLogLogPlot` with a list of values for from your functions.

```
points = Transpose[{{x1[#], #}, {x2[#], #}} & /@ Range[10^-4, 100, (100 - 10^-4)/200]];

ListLogLogPlot[points, Joined -> True]
```

[image]

I've used 200 plot points to get a nice smooth plot.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it is not work correctly for my complicated X functions.