# Plot time along the y-axis?

Tags: plotting, date-and-time

How can I plot times along the Y-axis, (with dates along the X-axis) e.g.
`{{DateObject[{2016,1,1}], TimeObject[{6,0,0}]}, {DateObject[{2016,1,2}], TimeObject[{8,0,0}]}}` so that the labels on the Y-axis have reasonable values? (i.e., not using `AbsoluteTime`)

For example, if I have the list of the sunrise and sunset times for the next year, how can I plot them with dates along the x-axis and times along the y-axis?

Comment: Have you tried `DateListPlot`?

Comment: That only works for the x-axis

Comment: Sorry, I somehow ignored that detail. :o

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like `DataListPlot` does not understand `TimeObject`s.  You can convert them to `Quantity` `"Hours"` and plot this instead.

```
data = {{DateObject[{2016, 1, 1}], TimeObject[{6, 0, 0}]},
        {DateObject[{2016, 1, 2}], TimeObject[{8, 0, 0}]}};

hrData = MapAt[UnitConvert[Total@DateValue[#, {"Hour", "Minute", "Second"}, Quantity], "Hours"] &, {All, 2}]@data
```

> {{DateObject[{2016, 1, 1}], Quantity[6, "Hours"]}, {DateObject[{2016, 1, 2}], Quantity[8, "Hours"]}}

Then plot `hrData`

```
DateListPlot[hrData, FrameLabel -> Automatic, 
 DateTicksFormat -> {"MonthNameShort", " ", "Day"}]
```

[image]

The y-axis is in hours and gets an automatic "h" frame label.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

I can't seem to find a built-in way so I propose an extension of my old [`axisFlip` routine](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18669/121):

```
axisFlip = # /. {x_Point | x_Line | x_GraphicsComplex :> MapAt[# ~Reverse~ 2 &, x, 1], 
     x : ((PlotRange | FrameTicks) -> _) :> x ~Reverse~ 2} &;

DateListPlot[{1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 11}, {2000, 8}] // axisFlip
```

[image]

```
DateListPlot[{1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 11}, {2000, 8}, Joined -> False] // axisFlip
```

[image]

This should work with `TimeObject` as well; let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: What if my x-axis is already a DateObject? I'll update the question.

Comment: @Soumya I don't think I understand the problem; please describe it explicitly.  Anyway I am sleepy and I'm going to bed, but I'll take another look tomorrow.

Comment: In my case I'm trying to plot sunrise and sunset times, but I can imagine this being useful to track workout sessions, transit/commuting times, or even sleep habits.

Comment: How can I get this to plot points (the default for DateListPlot) rather than a line? I tried changing `x_Line` to `x_Point` but it did not work, in the sense that I got a blank plot. Using the option `PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.1]` (or some other size) did not work either, still a blank plot. Thx

Comment: @pdini I included `x_Point` myself (updated answer) and now it works in e.g. `DateListPlot[{1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 11}, {2000, 8}, Joined -> False] // axisFlip` in Mathematica 10.1.0.  Which version are you using?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, it works! I am using 10.0.2 but it worked. I am pretty sure I had tried `Joined -> False` earlier but for some reason it did not work. Anyway, thank you very much!