# Horizontal line filling with ListPlot

Tags: plotting, filling

I have a problem with presenting a plot. I have the following data:

```
data := {74.69, 45.47, 42.45, 54.54, 36.04, 31.76, 33.95}
```

and plot it simply as

```
ListPlot[data, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

Now, if I would add `Filling->Bottom` the data points are connected to the x-axis via vertical lines. I want to do the same, only to have the points connected to y-axis via horizontal lines. Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't see any option in `Filling` that would allow this, and the ideas [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33443/filling-a-curve-to-a-vertical-axis) tend to be for curves rather than points.

One simple workaround is

```
ListPlot[data, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}] /. 
 Point[a__] :> 
  Sequence[Point[a], Opacity[0.3], Line[{{0, #2}, {#1, #2}} & @@@ a]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You could make a function out of this, and it will work easily with multiple data sets being plotted

```
horizontalListPlotFill[listplot_, axisOrigin_: 0] := 
  listplot /. 
   Point[a__] :> 
    {Point[a], Opacity[0.3], 
     Line[{{axisOrigin, #2}, {#1, #2}} & @@@ a]};
horizontalListPlotFill@ListPlot[{RandomReal[{10, 50}, {6, 2}],
   RandomReal[{10, 20}, {6, 2}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: great, tnx! Another related question - is it possible to switch the x and y axes? (so that the numbers in the data are represented on the x-axis). Transpose and such doesn't work here, because I don't have 2 coordinates per point...

Comment: @user42359 - `data2 = Transpose[{data, Range[Length[data]]}]`

Comment: @user42359 Bob's method is great, my thought was to use `MapIndexed`:  `MapIndexed[{#1, First@#2} &, data] // 
  ListPlot // horizontalListPlotFill`

Comment: Any reason to prefer `Sequence` here?  A List works as well apparently, and I like the idea of directives such as `Opacity[0.3]` being restricted anyway.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - good point, I had to check why it was still working at all and not rendering the second set of points as transparent, and I'm saved here by the fact that the directives and points with different styles are already in their own lists.

Answer (score 8):

One can add a horizontal `Filling` using [`Epilog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html).

```
data = {74.69, 45.47, 42.45, 54.54, 36.04, 31.76, 33.95}

ListPlot[data, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
 Epilog -> {ColorData[97, 1], MapIndexed[Line[{{0, #}, {First@#2, #}}] &, data]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I like to use [my `axisFlip` function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/104730/121) for [things like this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18669/121).

```
axisFlip = # /. {x_Line | x_GraphicsComplex :> MapAt[# ~Reverse~ 2 &, x, 1], 
     x : ((PlotRange | FrameTicks) -> _) :> x ~Reverse~ 2} &;

ListPlot[
  MapIndexed[{#, #2[[1]]} &, data]
  , AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}
  , Filling -> Axis
] // axisFlip
```

[image]