# How to rotate the curve but not the axes?

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have a such graphic:

```
data = {{0, 5}, {1.9, 7.5}, {0, 12}, {-5, 15.5}, {-1.2, 33.4}};
p=Plot[Interpolation[Reverse /@ data, x, InterpolationOrder -> 2], {x, 
  0, 55}, Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[.01], Point[Reverse /@ data]}]
```

[image]

But acutually this picture is expected(except that ticks label rotated)

[image]

Note the `interpolation method` should be used,but not the `fit method` here.How to get such graphic?

---

### Update:

I get a lot solution in following answers.But I realize if I have a option `Filling -> Axis` in my `p`.All solution cannot work anymore.

[image]

Comment: Closely related: [(18655)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18655/121), [(104727)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/104727/121)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
p = Plot[Interpolation[Reverse /@ data, x, InterpolationOrder -> 2], {x, 0, 55}, 
         Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[.01], Point[Reverse /@ data]}, Filling -> Axis]
```

You can post-process `p` to rotate the graphics primitives:

```
Show[Normal[p] /. prim : _Line | _Point | _Polygon :> 
   GeometricTransformation[prim, RotationTransform[Pi/2]], 
 PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> GoldenRatio]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Congratulation for *100K*. :) And I realize if we have a option `Filling -> Axis` in `p`.The rotate graphic cannot include anymore?

Comment: Thank you @yode. Please the new version to deal with `Filling`.

Answer (score 9):

This is pretty neat:

```
data = {{0, 5}, {1.9, 7.5}, {0, 12}, {-5, 15.5}, {-1.2, 33.4}};
iFun = Interpolation[Reverse[data, 2], InterpolationOrder -> 2];
ParametricPlot[Cross[{x, iFun[x]}], {x, 0, 55}, AspectRatio -> GoldenRatio, 
               Epilog -> {Directive[Red, PointSize[.01]],
                          Point[Cross /@ Reverse[data, 2]]}]
```

[image: rotated plot]

I'll leave fiddling with the ticks up to you.

Answer (score 6):

```
data = {{0, 5}, {1.9, 7.5}, {0, 12}, {-5, 15.5}, {-1.2, 33.4}};
plot = Plot[
   Interpolation[Reverse /@ data, x, InterpolationOrder -> 2], {x, 0, 
    55}, Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[.01], Point[Reverse /@ data]}];


Graphics[
   Rotate[{#, Epilog /. {##2}}, Pi/2, {0, 0}], 
   AspectRatio -> GoldenRatio, Axes -> True
] & @@ plot
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

For your updated example:

```
data = {{0, 5}, {1.9, 7.5}, {0, 12}, {-5, 15.5}, {-1.2, 33.4}};

p = Plot[Interpolation[Reverse /@ data, x, InterpolationOrder -> 2], {x, 0, 55}, 
  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[.01], Point[Reverse /@ data]}, Filling -> Axis]
```

A variation of `axisFlip` from [How can I transpose x and y axis on a Plot?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18655/how-can-i-transpose-x-and-y-axis-on-a-plot/18669#18669) and [Plot time along the y-axis?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/104727/plot-time-along-the-y-axis/104730#104730)

```
axisRotate = # /. {x_Point | x_Line | x_GraphicsComplex :> 
      MapAt[(#.{{0, 1}, {-1, 0}}) &, x, 1]} &;

Show[axisRotate@p, AspectRatio -> GoldenRatio/1, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Tick labels still show negative values however.  If we are going to fiddle with tick labels another approach opens up: just counter-rotate the labels:

```
rR = {#, Rotate[#, -90 °]} &;

Show[p, Ticks -> {rR /@ Range[10, 50, 10], rR /@ Range[20, 60, 20]}] // 
 Rotate[#, 90 °] &
```

[image]

This is not as nice for further processing and use so I favor the first method.

Comment: An alternative is to use `GeometricTransformation`, as in: `p /. Graphics[g_, r___] :> 
  Graphics[GeometricTransformation[g, RotationTransform[Pi/2]], 
   PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> GoldenRatio, r]`

Comment: @CarlWoll That certainly could be useful for more complicated transformations, but is there any advantage in this case over `Dot`?

Comment: It is useful because you don't have to have consider every possible `Graphics` primitive, e.g., `Arrow`, `Polygon`, etc. The OP example only has `Point` and `Line`, so using explicit rules for these objects works just as well.

Comment: @CarlWoll I overlooked that part of your code entirely.  Thanks!

Comment: @CarlWoll Your method misses the `Epilog` graphics which is undesirable for the example at hand.  What solution do you propose for that?  One could target `Epilog` expressly but I wonder if there is a more general way in the spirit of that replacement rule.

Comment: Yes, just target Epilog/Prolog as well.

Comment: Alternatively, one could first use FullGraphics to move the Epilog/Prolog options into the primitives argument.

Comment: @CarlWoll Since you bring it up, would you perhaps be willing to answer http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83648/121?  I would really like to know if there is a plan for that function, official or otherwise.