# Can someone please help me in breaking down what this code means?

Tags: graphics, replacement, rotation, geometric-transform

I hope someone can assist me as I am pretty new to Mathematica and understanding the language is a bit of a hurdle.

I am trying to rotate a plot of interlaced circles by some angle without rotating the axis and this is the method that somewhat worked the best.

```
Show[
    Normal[someplot] /. prim : _Line | _Point | _Polygon :> 
           GeometricTransformation[prim, RotationTransform[Pi/20]], PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> Automatic
     ]
```

From the highest rated answer in the link below:

[How to rotate the curve but not the axes?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/135376/how-to-rotate-the-curve-but-not-the-axes?newreg=6524330b8b1346808f64822ba50d92ea)

I would please like to know what the code below is doing. Particularly the **"`/. prim : _Line | _Point | _Polygon :>`"** part.

Thank you dearly.

Comment: In Mathematica, highlight any unknown symbol and press `F1` for help. `/.` links to [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html), `:` links to [`Pattern`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pattern.html), `_` links to [`Blank`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blank.html), and `:>` links to [`RuleDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed.html). Mathematica provides easy access to docs.

Answer (score 4):

`Normal[p]` is needed to replace [`GraphicsComplex`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphicsComplex.html) by a full form with all coodinates.

`prim : _Line | _Point | _Polygon` is a pattern that matches a line, point or polygon.

`:> GeometricTransform[prim,..]` replaces the matched line, point or polygon by a rotated version of it.

Here is a small example:

```
p= Graphics[{Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}], Point[{1, 0.5}]}, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

```
p /. prim : _Line | _Point | _Polygon :> 
  GeometricTransformation[prim, RotationTransform[Pi/2]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. This was of much help!