# Flip the axes in the Histogram Plot

Tags: plotting, code-review, code-request

I have a matrix and I would like to plot the square of its element.

```
n = 10;
H = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, n}];;
MatrixForm@H
H1=H*H;
Histogram[H1[[1]]]
```

[image: Histogram Plot]

First row is `H1[[1]]`

```
{0.977106, 0.720555, 0.230498, 0.432439, 0.180738, 0.0134593, \
0.592225, 0.0321264, 0.587188, 0.333721}
```

I got this, I wanted these values to be along $y$ and there position in columns to be along $x$. I saw this [How can I transpose $x$ and $y$ axis on a Plot?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18655/how-can-i-transpose-x-and-y-axis-on-a-plot). But this unnecessary complicated to just switch them and also it is for a function and I have list data. Is there any simple way to do that.

*NOTE*

Values along $X $ $->$ Like probabilities and $Y $ $->$ Locations (like 1st site, 2nd site, and so on). Want to see the plot otherway.

Comment: @Kuba I would like to maintain the plot on top of X-axes only values to be switched. Even values also get switched, so no change as such.

Comment: Your question still isn't clear. It sounds like maybe you just want a default-style histogram of your data sorted the other way? In that case use `Transpose`.

Comment: @dionys Please tell me if anything is unclear, I will try to clear it(but editing my question). `Transpose` will not work.I have tried. See the edited, if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Module[{n = 10, data, h1}, data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, n}];
 Print@data[[1]];
 h1 = Part[data^2, 1]; Print@h1;
 Print@Histogram[h1, PlotLabel -> "default histogram view"];
 RectangleChart[Transpose[{Array[1 &, n], h1}], 
  PlotLabel -> "rectangle chart view", 
  ChartLabels -> ToString /@ Range[10]]]

(*{0.336058,0.976536,0.507958,0.436267,0.1567,0.223463,0.760768,0.996779,0.532131,0.217988}*)

(*{0.112935,0.953623,0.258022,0.190329,0.0245549,0.0499356,0.578768,0.993568,0.283163,0.0475189}*)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Good One, this solves my problem. But I would like to do this for each row(one histogram plot for each row, as above), to convey my problem I showed you one row. Do I need to change h1 everytime? Or I can make h1 a matrix and change the row ?

Comment: Just use `Part` to select the appropriate row from your H1 (squared matrix data) and plot it with `RectangleChart`.

Comment: +1 .But for large $n$ isn't it a problem. Writing everytime new row or can we make a loop, which will select the row automatically and histogram plot for that?

Comment: Read the help docs for `Map` and `Part` carefully. You can apply `Part` and generate the plots for all rows by mapping a function over your squared data. You could do it in a loop as well, but it's messier and less efficient. Also, read the help for `Table` before you resort to procedural for-loops.

Comment: I am sorry to disturb you again, but why I am not getting the x coordinates

Comment: Even not in your plot the x-cord. are displayed, another the width of the data is increasing not fixed.

Comment: See the edited answer which shows x-axis labels and uniform widths.

Comment: A last disturbance, my boss said when I change row i.e. data[[1]] to data[[2]] then y-axis also changes means it re scales(where we have 1 it becomes 0.3 etc.). Is there a way to fix the scaling. So scale remain fixed.