# Rotating `DensityPlot`

Tags: plotting

I have a `DensityPlot` of `Tan[x - y]` as follows.

[image]

I want to set different View Point. (As I know `ViewPoint` is not active in `DensityPlot`)

When I rotate the `DensityPlot`, frame labels, plot legends, and axis also rotate. How to set correct frame labels, plot legends,  and axis numbers?

```
    plot = DensityPlot[Tan[x - y], {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 5}, 
   Mesh -> Automatic, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, FrameLabel -> {x, y}, PlotLegends -> Automatic];
 Rotate[plot, Pi/2]
```

[image]

I want to get a figure as follows: (But, on the x-axis, the large values can be at the top and small values at the bottom.)

[image]

Comment: did you try the replace of `x` and `y` in `{x,0,5},{y,0,5}`?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are trying to achieve. Can you make a mock-up example to illustrate it? (Show a picture that approximated the result you want.) Do you want the frame rotated? Do you want the contents rotated (that's a coordinate transofrmation)?

Comment: I edited my post according to your suggestion @Szabolcs

Comment: I would call this exchanging the x and y axes, not rotation. When I read "rotation", I though you want to rotate by an arbitrary amount.

Comment: There were prior questions on this, see e.g. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18655/12 You can simply exchange the x and y variables in your formula and label the axes accordingly. Or do you also want to invert the x axis, so large values are at the bottom and small values at the top?

Comment: On the x-axis, the large values can be at the top and small values at the bottom.

Comment: To flip the axis, take a look at `ScalingFunctions`, in particular e.g. `ScalingFunctions->{"Reverse",None,None}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to explore some of the range of possibilities from @Lukas_Lang's comment:

```
plot = DensityPlot[Tan[x - y], {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 5}, 
    Mesh -> Automatic, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, FrameLabel -> {x, y}, 
    PlotLegends -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 250, 
    ScalingFunctions -> #] & /@ {
   {None, None, None},
   {"Reverse", None, None},
   {"Reverse", "Reverse", None},
   {"Reverse", "Reverse", "Reverse"},
   {"Reverse", None, "Reverse"}
   }
```

[image]

This preserves the OP's original `x` & `y` values/ranges.
Not certain if it gives them what they need.