How to swap axes in ListLinePlot?
I want to transpose the figure produced by ListLinePlot[RandomFunction[RandomWalkProcess[0.5], {0, 30}]].
How to do that?

Strongly related, if not duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18669/1871

ListLinePlot[   RandomFunction[RandomWalkProcess[0.5], {0, 30}],   CoordinatesToolOptions -> {"DisplayCoordinates" -> Transpose} ]

$Version

(* "14.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

SeedRandom[1234];

llp = ListLinePlot[RandomFunction[RandomWalkProcess[0.5], {0, 30}]]


Extract the line and reverse the points:
Graphics[{ColorData[97][1], AbsoluteThickness[2],
  Map[Reverse, Cases[llp, _Line, All][[1]], {2}]},
 Axes -> True, AspectRatio -> GoldenRatio]



Borrowing the setup from Bob Hanlon's answer and,
Using ReflectionTransform:
Clear["Global`*"];
SeedRandom[1234];
llp = ListLinePlot[RandomFunction[RandomWalkProcess[0.5], {0, 30}]];


llpv = Show[llp /. L_Line :> {Red, GeometricTransformation[L
       , ReflectionTransform[{-1, 1}]]
      }, PlotRange -> Reverse@PlotRange@llp
   , AspectRatio -> GoldenRatio
   ];

GraphicsRow[{llp, llpv}]



