# Flipping Vertical Axis in ParametricPlot

Tags: plotting

Basically, I'm trying to "rotate" a plot clockwise so that the former x-axis is pointing down, and the former y-axis is pointing to the right. From reading some answers on here, I gathered that I can get axes in the right general orientations using `ParametricPlot`:

```
ParametricPlot[{Sin[7 x] - 1,x}, {x, 0, 1}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-3, 0}, {0, 1}}, 
  Frame -> True, 
  AspectRatio -> 5/8, 
  FrameLabel -> {"Label 1", "Label 2"}]
```

[image: plot]

But the problem is that the vertical axis still points up, and I need it to be going the other direction: I need it to be 0 at the top and 1 at the bottom.

Does anyone have any solution to this? `ScalingFunctions` would have worked beautifully from what I've been reading, but this seems to have been "fixed" years ago without a similar functionality put in to replace it.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If I understand correctly, try ParametricPlot[{Sin[7x]-1, -x}, {x,0,1}] i.e. flip the new "y" by adding a minus sign.

Comment: That does seem to work, but the frame labels are now wrong, as in the labels are negative. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: does Rotate[plot,-Pi/2] work?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: @Algohi. Your approach has an issue -- it also rotates the frame labels and the tick labels, which I think is not wanted.

Comment: Yup, I want the frame labels and tick labels to have proper orientations. Oh, and thanks for fixing the code block, m_goldberg.

Comment: Related: [(6204898)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6204898/121), [(7191)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7191/121), [(7859)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7859/121), [(13253)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13253/121), [(18655)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18655/121)

Comment: I have marked this as a duplicate.  I believe what you want is accomplished through `FrameTicks`.  Does this not give the correct output?:  `ParametricPlot[{Sin[7 x] - 1, -x}, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {Automatic, {-#, #} & /@ Range[0, 1, 0.2]}]`

Comment: In *Mathematica 10* `ScalingFunctions` *does* work too: `ParametricPlot[{Sin[7 x] - 1, x}, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, ScalingFunctions -> {Identity, "Reverse"}]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. To get what the OP wants, you have to invert the aspect ratio and swap the frame labels as in my answer.

Comment: @m_goldberg Sorry, I should have left those out entirely; such parameters were immaterial to the underlying method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for.

```
ParametricPlot[{t, - (Sin[7 t] - 1)}, {t, 0, 1}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 3}},
  AspectRatio -> 8/5,
  FrameTicks -> {{Table[{i, -i}, {i, 0., 3., .5}], None}, {Automatic, None}},
  Frame -> True,
  FrameLabel -> {"Label 2", "Label 1"}]
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun (but somewhat ridiculous to me):

```
With[{r = RotationMatrix[-Pi/2]}, 
 ParametricPlot[r.{Sin[7 x] - 1, x}, {x, 0, 1}, 
  PlotRange -> (r.{{-3, 0}, {0, 1}}), Frame -> True, 
  AspectRatio -> 5/8, FrameLabel -> {"Label 1", "Label 2"}]]
```

[image]